# Direct sums and the Rank nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I had recently proved a result when solving an assignment problem that said,

> Given a vector space $L$ and a projection operator (linear operator
>   that is idempotent),  $$ p:L \rightarrow L  $$ Prove that $L = \ker{p}\bigoplus im(p)$

In this proof I had explicitly used the fact that $p^2=p$.

My query arrises here - how does this reconcile with the fact that, from the rank-nullity theorem, we know that for **any** linear transformation $T : V \rightarrow V$ we have that,
$$
T \cong \ker{T}\bigoplus im(T)
$$
where $V$ is finite dimensional with $T \in End(V)$ in this case.

This seems to imply that the requirement that the linear operator be a projection was never necessary...is that true?

I feel like I'm missing something blatantly obvious.

**UPDATE**: I think I see it. Is this because in the rank-nullity theorem we require $V$ to be finite dimensional to make the isomorphism claim, however in the above given problem $L$ needn't be?

I just realized in my proof that I never enforced the basis to be finite.I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could confirm if this is what I was missing or is there something else going on?

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between internal direct sum and external direct sum? When $p$ is a projection, the fact that $L = \ker p \oplus \operatorname{im} p$ (notice the strict equality here) actually tells you something about the subspaces $\ker p, \operatorname{im} p$ of $L$ and how they "sit" inside $L$ (they intersect trivially and complement each other **inside** $L$). In the statement $L \cong \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im} T$, the direct sum is an external one, hence you only get an isomorphism but it doesn't tell you anything about how the subspaces "sit" inside $L$.

Comment: @levap Thanks, that makes sense. If you post that as answer I would gladly accept that and mark it closed. Also, does what I wrote in my update have anything to do with what's going on?